# How is the Mann-Whitney U statistic calculated in SPSS?

Tags: spss, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I get different results using NPTESTS and NPAR TESTS in SPSS for the U-statistic. Can someone please tell me which formula is used for these two procedures, respectively.

It looks like NPAR TESTS uses the same formula as wilcox.test() in R.

SPSS Syntax:

NPAR TESTS

/M-W= Var BY Grp(1 2)

/MISSING ANALYSIS.

Yields a Mann-Whitney U of 211.000 (and changing the reference group around does not change U)

*Nonparametric Tests: Independent Samples.

NPTESTS

/INDEPENDENT TEST (Var) GROUP (Grp)

/MISSING SCOPE=ANALYSIS USERMISSING=EXCLUDE

/CRITERIA ALPHA=0.05  CILEVEL=95.

Yields a Mann-Whitney U of 589.000

Sample Data:

Group 1:
c(.00,.00,2.00,1.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,3.00,8.00,5.00,6.00,9.00,11.00,2.00,1.00,2.00,3.00)

Group 2: 
c(3.00,4.00,5.00,12.00,14.00,15.00,21.00,3.00,4.00,12.00,34.00,12.00,5.00,6.00,18.00,23.00,22.00,22.00,14.00,1.00,2.00,.00,.00,15.00,3.00,23.00,10.00,11.00,19.00,1.00,11.00,15.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,5.00,4.00,3.00,2.00,1.00)

Comment: The sum of the ranks in group1 is 211. The sum of the ranks in group2 is 589. It doesn't matter whether you look at the smallest group, the largest group or the first listed group, as long as you correctly account for the one you use in calculating the distribution. It appears that there was a discrepancy over p-values in SPSS that may have led to confusion [see here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21485598), but I don't think that's an issue here.

Comment: Yes, from a 'significance' point of view it doesn't matter (40*20 - 211 = 589 - these values are interchangeable) - was really just confused over the two different values being given within SPSS in two different procedures...and thanks for the link. I should have noted: I'm using SPSS version 20.

Comment: Interestingly, I just had an example with the exact same U value and different p-values generated by SPSS and R (double checking some figures - after 20 or so identical results...this one shows up as different...0.949 vs 0.956).

Comment: That's likely to be a difference in treatment of ties, but it's possible it's a difference of when they move from exact distribution to normal approximation.

Comment: That seems reasonable - there are many ties in the other values I checked too though...or there is a difference in exact vs approx. Either way, it's not a big deal, just curious. Odd that only one turned out with a different p-value.

Comment: It is odd, but if it's a difference of when you change from one approximation to another, it may be that there's only a very small window of values of sample size(s) where one uses exact and the other doesn't. At larger or smaller sample sizes they could well agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[NPAR Tests:](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/alg_npar_tests.htm)**

> If a WEIGHT variable is specified, it is used to replicate a case as
>   many times as indicated by the weight value rounded to the nearest
>   integer. If the workspace requirements are exceeded and sampling has
>   been selected, a random sample of cases is chosen for analysis using
>   the algorithm described in SAMPLE... The tests are described in (Siegel, 1956. Nonparametric statistics for the behavioral sciences. New York: McGraw-Hill.).

and the description of NPAR TESTS: Mann-Whitney U Test is [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/alg_npar_tests_mannwhitney.htm).

In the category of "*Nonparametric Tests Algorithms > Independent Samples Tests (nonparametric tests algorithms)*" there is the "*Mann-Whitney Test (nonparametric tests algorithms)*" described with all formula details [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/alg_nonparametric_independent_mann-whitney.htm).

Those links should fully answer your question about how the statistic is calculated.  You may want to verify that the documentation is for the same version you're running, and try changing version numbers in the URL if not.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation isn't overly clear, but for anyone who doesn't want to wade through it - the one test yields n1*n2 - U while the other yields U.